# hover class is not working. I'm using tailwindcss CLI

Tags: css, hover, tailwind-css

```
<ul class="flex flex-col justify-center items-start gap-2 w-[100%]">
        <button
          class=" action-btn bg-transparent hover:bg-[#272e3f] text-[#fff] opacity-50 hover:opacity-100 w-full text-left py-2 px-2 rounded-sm  "
        >
          All Tasks
        </button>
        <button
          class=" action-btn bg-transparent hover:bg-[#272e3f] text-[#fff] opacity-50 hover:opacity-100 w-full text-left py-2 px-2 rounded-sm  "
        >
          Completed Tasks
        </button>
        <button
          class=" action-btn bg-transparent hover:bg-[#272e3f] text-[#fff] opacity-50 hover:opacity-100 w-full text-left py-2 px-2 rounded-sm  "
        >
          Uncompleted Tasks
        </button>
      </ul>
```

I tried everything, that can be possible. but it didn't work. please fix the issue if there is ...

Comment: Consider checking the file the code is in is covered by the `content` file globs in the Tailwind configuration or `--content` flag.

Comment: /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['./*.html'],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}

Comment: everything working fine except hover class

Comment: Consider checking the file the code is in is covered by the `content` file globs in the Tailwind configuration or `--content` flag. It could be that the classes used are covered by code in other files.

Comment: i couldn't  understand, what are you saying